# Plum cake recipe

Tags: baking, cake, flour, dried-fruit

After all its a Christmas month so I wanted to something different so tried to do plum cake. But that ended up really mess. I got the recipe from blog did some variations to that but the cake ended up very bad I didn't get the Pic of it. Here is the recipe of what I did

750 Gram Mixed dry fruits (raisins, black currants, cranberries) mixed it in grape juice and left it overnight
1 1/2 cups All purpose flour
1 Zest of lemon
1 Zest of orange
1/4 tsp Clove powder
1/2 tsp Ginger powder
1/2 tsp Cinnamon powder
50 Gram Tuti fruity
250 Gram Butter - I used melted butter
200 Gram Brown sugar
1/2 tsp Baking powder
100 Gram Almond powder
1 tsp Vanilla essence

I did not use eggs in this recipe.

I mixed all the above said ingredients and the batter was thick for me so I added little hot water and then added some more melted butter to it. Then greased a pan and baked it using a pressure cooker.

After some time when I checked the cake it was very light brown in color and it was cooked all the sides so I took it out. After some time when I checked I could see the bottom of the cake was exactly the same color what i was expecting dark brown color. Also when I tried cutting the cake it was not in a proper form. It started breaking in to small pieces.

I am not sure of what is wrong in this. For brown color I can try caramelizing the white sugar. But I am not sure why It broke in to pieces. Can anyone please help me me to correct my mistake. I want to make this again next week. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What was the original recipe? Why didn't you stick to it?

Comment: The above list is the original one but we don't eat eggs so I tried to make it with out eggs. Also I have tried several other cakes with out egg it came out really well.

Comment: Just for clarification: You picked a recipe you never made before and left out the eggs, or you changed a recipe that you (successfully) made before? And did the original recipe call for melted butter, or was that another modification of yours?

Comment: And did the original recipe say “bake in a pressure cooker” or was it designed for an oven?

Comment: @Stephie Even if it didn't say pressure cooker, that method isn't unusual in India and this appears to be an Indian recipe (the tutti frutti will mean dried papaya in this instance). 'Plum cake' is the common term for what speakers of some other englishes might call fruit cake.

Comment: @Spagirl I was asking for clarification, because like swapping ingredients changing the method can (and probably will) have an influence. I absolutely know that this oven alternative is common in some regions.

Comment: As plum cake in this case doesn't involve plums (see also plum pudding) I've removed the tag about that specific fruit.  I've created a new *dried-fruit* tag to cover questions about this common class of ingredients

Answer (score 3):

Without butter creamed into the sugar (soft but not melted), there is almost nothing to give the cake structure.  A pound cake would have 200g to 250g of flour and 4 eggs. Even supposing 4 eggs in the original recipe, 750g of fruit is a lot for this amount of batter to support.

Ground almond can be a reasonable substitute for flour in cakes (you don't want gluten development), but for a heavy fruit cake like this, I would suggest flour.

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for your reply but I have tried other cakes as well with out eggs and I got the perfect texture and taste. I am not sure as why not this.

Answer (score 2):

just because some earlier experiments in removing eggs from an egg-based cake recipe succeeded does not mean it always will. Eggs play different roles in different cakes. I think here it plays in structure-building and without eggs it would fall apart. If you want to have eggless plum cake I would advise you to start with a recipe that is eggless.